# Can i create multiple Today extensions for the same containing app in ios

Tags: ios, today-extension

Can i create multiple Today extensions for the same containing app in ios?
Will Apple allows multiple today extensions to be shown for single app in its Today view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out we can create multiple extensions to a single containing app ,even 2 today Extensions for same app.